# Redirect directory to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't figure it out at all, does anyone know how to describe a link with `.htaccess` of:

```
example.com/bedrijven/marketing-metrics/
```

to

```
marketing-metrics.example.com/
```

I have found this on this forum but it wasn't the solution

```
RewriteRule ^(bedrijven/$1.*)$ https:///$1.example.com/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

is there anybody who can help?

Comment: "I have found this on this forum" - Do you mind sharing exactly where you found this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^bedrijven/([^/]+)/$ https://$1.example.com/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

The `$1` is a backreference to the first capturing group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument), ie. whatever is matched by `([^/]+)`. It makes no sense to use a backreference like this in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* itself, as you used in your example.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply but this wasn't the solution for me

Comment: So, what was the solution for you? In what way does this not work? Do you have other directives in your .htaccess file?

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^bedrijven/([^/]+)/$ https://$1.betaalplugin.nl/ [R=301,L,NC]


I used this code but it didn't work..

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Do you get an error? An incorrect redirect? Nothing? Have you confirmed that `.htaccess` overrides are allowed and that mod_rewrite is enabled?